# Casting pointer to void when printing

Tags: c, pointers

I've been trying to work through some C fundamentals lately to try and build a basic understanding of lower level languages.
In one of the documents I've encountered ([A tutorial on pointers and arrays in C](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/readings/pointers.pdf))
the author uses a void pointer in a `printf` statement:

```
int var = 2;
printf("var has the value %d and is stored at %p\n", var, (void *) &var);
```

And states the reason:

> I cast the pointers to integers into void
>   pointers to make them compatible with the %p conversion specification.

However, omitting the `(void *)` does not result in an error or warning, either compiling and running or running through `valgrind`.

```
int var = 2;
printf("var has the value %d and is stored at %p\n", var, &var);
```

Is casting to void here considered a best practice or standard, or is there something more sinister afoot?

Comment: It is impossible to check experimentally whether you have written correct C. A program is correct C if it follows the rules, that's all you can do.

Comment: It is just being explicit, a cast literally says "I am taking this value to be interpreted this specific way". In your example you're casting an `int*` to a `void*`. So take my integer pointer to be interprets as a generic pointer. Personally, being so verbose doesn't seem like great practice for trivial situations like this.

Comment: Pointers to different types are permitted to have different representations and alignment  restrictions. `printf()` is a variadic function, which doesn't automatically convert its arguments to the type of its parameters, so calling it with arguments of the wrong type leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Omitting the cast is strictly _undefined behaviour_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `printf` is a variadic function, its declaration only specifies the type of the first parameter (the format string). The number and types of any remaining parameters are required to match the format string, but it's up to you, the programmer, to make sure they actually match. If they don't, the behavior is undefined, but the compiler isn't obliged to warn you about it. (Some compilers, including gcc, can do some checking if the format string is a literal.)

The `%p` format specifier requires an argument of type `void*`. If you pass a pointer of a different type, you have undefined behavior. In many implementations, all pointer types have the same size and representation, and are passed the same way as function arguments -- but the language doesn't guarantee that. By explicitly converting the pointer to `void*`, you guarantee that it will work correctly. By omitting the cast, you have code that will *probably* work as you expect it to on almost all implementations.

100% correct is better than 99% correct, especially if the only cost of that extra 1% is typing a few characters.